# How to compare differnt node value fields using angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I compare both node Uid == ChById.

[image: first node]

[image: second node]

1. this code for first node value access. 
   provides into badminton sports uid access into array.

   ```
   this.db.list('/Providers/'+this.mySport+'', {preserveSnapshot:     true}).subscribe(snapshots => {
   if(snapshots.values()==null) {console.log('its empty')}else {
   snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
     snapshot.forEach(snapshot1 => {
       var myTeamName = [snapshot1.val().team_name];
       var availability = [snapshot1.val().Availability];
       var userid = [snapshot1.val().Uid];
       this.getallprovidersuserids = [userid];
       //console.log(this.getallprovidersuserids);
       this.allelementsofuser.push({teams: myTeamName, userloginid: userid, availability: availability});
     });
   });
   }
   });
   ```

   2. this code for second node access.
      challanges node into badminton sports ChById value accessing into array value.

      ```
      this.db.list('/Challenges/'+this.mySport+'', {
        preserveSnapshot: true}).subscribe(snapshots2 => {
        snapshots2.forEach(snapshot2 => {
          snapshot2.forEach(snapshot3 => {
            var getallChallenegesuserid = [snapshot3.val().ChByUid];
            console.log(getallChallenegesuserid[0]);
          });
        });
        // console.log(this.getallprovidersuserids);
       });
      ```

   if i store both value two different arrays and compare both using nested for loop.its not given output.please help to solve my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `combineLatest` so they resolve at the same time (they're both async + lazy):

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    this.db.list(`/Providers/${this.mySport}`,  {preserveSnapshot: true}),
    this.db.list(`/Challenges/${this.mySport}`, {preserveSnapshot: true})
).subscribe(([providersSnapshot, challengesSnapshot]) => {
   // do your comparison in here
})
```

Comment: thank you @James Daniels. your solution working my program successfully.

Comment: hello @James Daniels Challenges value are less than Providers value,for a example all providers childs values are 41 and challeneges node values 18,foreach undefine error given.